# What is the strength of a Kree as compared to an Asgardian or a human?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, aliens, agents-of-shield

As determined by the answers to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260325/do-average-asgardians-have-superhuman-strength-in-mcu), Asgardians can lift up to 30 tons in the comics and are, at least to a degree, stronger than the average human in the MCU. However, throughout Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. and especially in Season 5, we see multiple Kree warriors and other members of the Kree species. They seem to at times be matched by people such as Melinda May or Daisy Johnson, but compared to a human, what is the strength of a Kree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Official Handbooks, the comicbook versions of **Kree are about twice as strong as normal humans.**

> Outwardly humanoid to a large degree, Kree bodies are adapted to environmental characteristics on Hala that are un-Earthlike: notably, higher gravity and a higher nitrogen content in the atmosphere. **Although the Kree cannot breathe Earth's atmosphere without special apparatus, their denser bodies afford them about twice the average human being's strength and endurance.** Despite their physical superiority and relatively advanced technology, the Kree race has reached the pinnacle of their evolutionary development.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol. 2 #7](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_2_7)* (June, 1986)</sub>

> TRAITS: **Kree bodies are denser and more durable than those of normal humans, making them about twice as strong,** though Pink (aka White) Kree have a greater range of differences in these areas than Blue Kree do.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z Vol. 1 #6](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_6)* (February, 2009)</sub>

Comment: Compare to say, Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson, who is three times as strong as normal humans.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham - Assuming Kree bodybuilders exist, then one of those could presumably be about twice as strong as him. But yes, he'd be stronger than an average Kree.